# Laravel Eloquent whereDate() with UnixTimestamps

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

the entries in my database have a custom timestamp field (e.g. 1488446089). 
How do I use whereDate() or whereDay() with unix timstamps?

This of course just works for Date Fields.

```
$posts = Post::whereDay('uploaded_time', '=', '2017-05-10')->get();
```

Comment: whereDay() through we can get only specific day records from your timestamps column, like if you want to get every month 10th day records, you can see bellow example with output.   $posts = Post::whereDay('uploaded_time', '=', '10')->get();

Comment: check out this link http://laraveldaily.com/eloquent-date-filtering-wheredate-and-other-methods/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is fetching all Posts, and then filtering the results in PHP:

```
    $myDate = '2017-05-10';

    $posts = Post::all()->filter(function (Post $post) use ($myDate) {
        $uploadedAt = Carbon::createFromTimestamp($post->uploaded_time)->format('Y-m-d');
        return $uploadedAt === $myDate;
    });
```

Why? Because if I'm right you are trying to fetch all posts that were uploaded on a certain **date**. This means that there is a range of timestamps valid. (60 * 60 * 24). With [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/) (comes with Laravel) you can easily convert your timestamps to `Y-m-d` formatted strings. Those you then compare to the date string of your choice.

**Edit**

I have no way to test this at the moment, but it should be possible to do this with a query builder after all:

```
$myDate = Carbon::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', '2017-05-10');
$startOfDayTimestamp = $myDate->startOfDay()->timestamp;
$endOfDayTimestamp = $myDate->endOfDay()->timestamp;

$posts = Post::whereBetween('uploaded_time', [
    $startOfDayTimestamp,
    $endOfDayTimestamp
])->get();
```

Here we create 2 timestamps, one for the very start of the date you wish to filter by, and one for the very end. After that, we can use the builder's [`whereBetween()`](https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses) method and pass the 2 timestamps.

[I found this solution here](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/code-review/carbonnow-and-timestamps?page=1), and simplified a little bit by replacing the `setTime()` calls with `startOfDay` and `endOfDay` methods.

Answer (score 2):

To run it correctly use `whereDate` instead of `whereDay`

```
$posts = Post::whereDate('uploaded_time', '2017-05-10')->get();
```

To get all specific day means (date of month like `1-30`)

```
$posts = Post::whereDay('uploaded_time', '10')->get();//provide date of month
```

get more detail : https://laravel.com/docs/master/queries#where-clauses